React antd Form populate data
Trying to populate Antd form items from a given key-value type object, with key as label and value as input parameter. I tried the following code, and I also searched online, but it did not work. What can I try next?
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';
const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log('Success:', values);
};
const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
};
const data = {
    fname: 'First',
    lname: 'Last',
    age: '31'
};
const MyForm = () => (
    <>
        <h2>My Data</h2>
        <Form
            onFinish={onFinish}
            onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
            initialValues={data}
        >
            {Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                <Form.Item label={key} name={key} >
                    <Input value={value} />
                </Form.Item>
            })}
        </Form>
    </>
);
export default MyForm;

Any workaround using react antd is also welcome

I think you should use map instead of forEach as forEach doesn't return anything.

Already tried that, did not work, no data shows up

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You have to use Array.prototype.map and callback function that you pass inside map function has to return a component or jsx element. Don't forget to write word return. Also in react loops you have to pass unique value among array items to the key prop.
{Object.keys(data).map((key, value) => {
    return <Form.Item label={key} name={key} key={key}>
      <Input value={value} />
    </Form.Item>;
})}

Other option is to use an arrow function without {}. In that case you don't need to write word return.
{Object.keys(data).map((key, value) => (
    <Form.Item label={key} name={key} key={key}>
      <Input value={value} />
    </Form.Item>;
)}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:
The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys.

Thank you, it worked actually.
could you please tell me why '(..)' worked, but with '{..}' had to add return statement explicitly?

Read these 2 topics https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions I believe you'll find answers there.

Yes, it's better to use map() method if you are writing to ES6. But you can continue to use the forEach() method. Use the keys property instead of entries. It goes like this:
{Object.keys(data).forEach((key, value) => {
    <Form.Item label={key} name={key}>
      <Input value={value} />
    </Form.Item>;
})}


already tried, did not work

You must use a map instead of foreach because forEach returns nothing, so the form elements are not rendered.
Here is an example :
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-bouman-59l8qc?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js
